# Specifying a request template for a aws_api_gateway_integration in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform

In the [Terraform documentation for AWS_API_GATEWAY_INTEGRATION](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html), the following parameters are supported:

- rest_api_id
- resource_id
- http_method
- type
- uri
- integration_http_method

They give this example:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method}"
  type = "MOCK"
}
```

But I would like to specify a mapping template (as well as a Lambda integration), as you can with the UI:

[image]

However I see no way of doing that with Terraform. Is is possible ?

**Note:** What I am currently doing is `apply`ing the rest of the configuration (lambda, s3, iam etc...), and then adding mapping template manually afterwards (as well as the integration type of lambda).

But then every time I `terraform apply` to apply some other config (eg: s3), Terraform reverts back the mapping template and the integration type.

The "reverting" plan looks like this:

```
~ aws_api_gateway_integration.post_hit_integration
    request_templates.#:                "1" => "0"
    request_templates.application/json: "{\n  \"body\" : $input.json('$'),\n  \"headers\": {\n    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())\n    \"$param\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))\" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end\n    \n    #end  \n  },\n  \"stage\" : \"$context.stage\"\n}" => ""
    uri:                                "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:000000000000:function:create_hit/invocations" => ""
```

Answer (score 29):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1036), here is a config that works:

(You have to use the params `uri`, `type`, `integration_http_method` and `request_templates`)

```
# API
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "my_api" {
  name = "my_api"
  description = "My Api for adding pets"
}

# Resource
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "pets_resource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "pets"
}

# Method
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "post_pet_method" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.pets_resource.id}"
  http_method = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

# Integration
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "post_pet_integration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.pets_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.post_pet_method.http_method}"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${aws_lambda_function.create_pet.arn}/invocations"
  type = "AWS"                           # Documentation not clear
  integration_http_method = "POST"       # Not documented
  request_templates = {                  # Not documented
    "application/json" = "${file("api_gateway_body_mapping.template")}"
  }
}
```

And contents of **api_gateway_body_mapping.template**:

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end  
  },
  "stage" : "$context.stage"
}
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this, thank you very much. I was about to start enumerating the headers exhaustively.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have it inline rather than in a separate template you can do:

```
request_templates = {                  
  "application/json" =  <<REQUEST_TEMPLATE
  {
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end  
  },
  "stage" : "$context.stage"
  }
  REQUEST_TEMPLATE
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Lambda function as the endpoint, the integration type would be "AWS".

Here is [the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source.html) that explains creating a Lambda integration.

Here is [a GitHub post](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/4295#issuecomment-179361843) that shows how this can be done using Terraform.

Hope that helps! Let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, I couldn't add the Mapping templates as my Integration type was "AWS_PROXY". I changed it to "AWS" and it worked.

Terraform wouldn't consider about mapping templates if the integration type is "AWS_PROXY"

You can learn more about [Integration types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html) here.